# Limit computations clarification needed

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

I think that the computation of limits is not very clear for me so here is an example to disccus.

Consider the function $f(x) = \frac{x\left[1+x(4-x^2)^{-1/2}\right] - x- 2 + (4-x^2)^{1/2}}{x^2}$
and we cant to compute the limit as $x$ tends to $0$. I have tried something, which is false for sure but I would like to know if I understand well the mistake.

First method (which is false) :

$$
\frac{x\left[1+x(4-x^2)^{-1/2}\right] - x- 2 + (4-x^2)^{1/2}}{x^2} = \frac{\left[1+x(4-x^2)^{-1/2}\right] }{x} + \frac{-x - 2 + (4-x^2)^{1/2}}{x^2}
$$

Then if we focus on the first term we have
$$
\frac{(4-x^2)^{1/2}+x}{x(4-x^2)^{1/2}} = \frac{\left[(4-x^2)^{1/2}+x\right]\left[(4-x^2)^{1/2} - x\right]}{x(4 - x^2)^{1/2}\left[(4 - x^2)^{1/2}-x\right]} = \frac{4 - 2x^2}{x(4-x^2) - x^2(4-x^2)^{1/2}} = \frac{\frac{4}{x} - 2x}{\left[(4-x^2) - x(4-x^2)^{1/2}\right]}
$$

Which leads to me think that this limit is infinity and thus, the limit of $f(x)$ when $x$ tends to $0$ does not exist in $^\mathbb{R}$ without having to look to the second term.

Now what is the mistake ? My guess is that I implicitly assuming that the limit of a sum is the sum of the limits whatever the limit of each term is which is false since this property holds only when the limit of each term is well defined. So I don't think my computation of the limit of this term is false, just it is not appropriate for the limit we want to compute.

Second method (which is correct) :

$$
\frac{x\left[1+x(4-x^2)^{-1/2}\right] - x- 2 + (4-x^2)^{1/2}}{x^2} = \frac{x^2(4-x^2)^{-1/2} - 2 + (4-x^2)^{1/2}}{x^2} = \frac{1}{(4-x^2)^{1/2}} + \frac{(4-x^2)^{1/2} - 2}{x^2}
$$

and by using the conjugate quantity we get

$$
\frac{1}{(4-x^2)^{1/2}}  + \frac{-x^2}{(4-x^2)^{1/2} + 2} \rightarrow_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{4}
$$

wich is ok since we have two well defined limit here.

So if I resume the "philisophy" of computing limits is : Tidy up until you have well-defined limits, otherwise conclude that they don't exist?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x+(-x)$ as $x\to\infty$. Both summands $x$ and $(-x)$ diverge as $x\to\infty$. Can you conclude $f(x)$ diverges, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(x)=x+(-x)$ as $x\to\infty$. Both summands $x$ and $(-x)$ diverge as $x\to\infty$. Can you conclude $f(x)$ diverges, too?

Your "philosophy" of computing limits is not 100% wrong, though. Let's say you "tidy up" $f$ into a form where you cannot proceed: $$f(x)=A(x)+B(x).$$

As my $x+(-x)$ example shows, if both $A$ and $B$ diverge as $x\to x_0$, you cannot conclude anything for $\lim_{x\to x_0}f$, because a sum of diverging quantities *still might converge*!

However, if you manage to reshuffle things around so that only one of the summands, say $A$, diverges, but $B$ converges, then your "philosophy" *does* apply, and you can surely conclude that $f$ *diverges* too. For if $\lim_{x\to x_0}f$ existed, then by rearranging $$B(x)=f(x)-A(x)\underset{x\to x_{0}}{\longrightarrow}\lim_{x\to x_0}f-\lim_{x\to x_0}A$$
would be a finite number, too, contradicting divergence of $B$.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this answer ! You've filled in what I've been missing ! I totally agree with you. However, the point of decomposing a term to calculate the limit is generally when that term doesn't admit a simple limit? In the example you give, there's no need to "tidy up until" since the result is direct (it is a constant)? So perhaps it would be more appropriate to say: if the limit isn't obvious, then we need to tidy up until we have limits (well-defined or not) to conclude, or am I missing something by saying that?